# Insert tags with PHP [Wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering if it's possible to add tags into articles not using the back-office, but with php ?

Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wp_set_post_tags will do the trick

```
wp_set_post_tags( 42, 'meaning,life', true );
```

see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags Examples section.

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_set_post_tags( $post_ID, $tags, $append )
```

Where:

```
$post_ID
    (integer) (required) Post ID.

        Default: 0 

$tags
    (string,array) (optional) List of tags. Can be an array or a comma separated string.

        Default: array 

$append
    (boolean) (optional) If true, tags will be appended to the post. If false, tags will replace existing tags.

        Default: false
```

Next time, use google yourself. ;)